# Wait for directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a `directive` for my `form` with a template that contain two `text fields`. The first `textfield` can be filled in with a `number` (`id`). As soon as the `focus` is lost in this `field`, a `GET` is done and the appropriate name for that `id` is filled in in the second `text field`. When a number is filled in that doesn't exist in the database (there is no name found), the `validation` will be `false` for that field.

The problem that I have is that, when you fill in a wrong number (-1 for example) and click straight on the "Save" button, my form will be submitted before the `GET` call and my directive will be valid instead of invalid.

Is there a way to let a function wait for a directive to complete its `Ajax` calls or something like that?

I have tried a `$timeout` with a `0` delay to place my function call (from the button) at the end of the queue but still, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The user can still click the button. You can communicate between the directive and the function in your controller that submits and wait for the result, only then continue with submission. (Show a loading straight away though so the user won't be confused)

Comment: I see what you mean, but how can I do this? I'm quite new to Angular as you may notice...

Comment: If the directive fires a `GET` request then you have a promise. Assign that promise to a variable on the directive scope so you can access it from the controller. Then you have in your controller `if (getPromise) { getPromise.then(function () { // submit }); }`

Comment: So you want to disable the `Save` button when the Ajax call starts and re-enable the `Save` button when the Ajax call completes? Is that what you want?

Comment: In fact, that is indeed what I am looking for. My save button gets disabled perfectly according to my validation (and $dirty state) except for my directive.

Comment: You should ask yourself if disabling the button will not confuse the users. They might not be aware why the button is getting disabled all of a sudden.

Comment: Omri, that will not be the problem since it will never confuse the user in my case. It is always disabled unless the form is valid and dirty.

Comment: What you want is provided by `$asyncValidators` which is part of `ngModelController`. For more info see the [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- $asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators). They withhold validation pending resolution of a promise.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is provided by `$asyncValidators` which is part of `ngModelController`. They withhold validation pending resolution of a promise.

From the Docs:

> `$asyncValidators` A collection of validations that are expected to
>         perform an asynchronous validation (e.g. a HTTP request). The validation function that is provided
>         is expected to return a promise when it is run during the model validation process. Once the promise
>         is delivered then the validation status will be set to true when fulfilled and false when rejected.
>         When the asynchronous validators are triggered, each of the validators will run in parallel and the model
>         value will only be updated once all validators have been fulfilled. As long as an asynchronous validator
>         is unfulfilled, its key will be added to the controllers `$pending` property. Also, all asynchronous validators
>         will only run once all synchronous validators have passed.
>
> Please note that if $http is used then it is important that the server returns a success HTTP response code in order to fulfill the validation and a status level of `4xx` in order to reject the validation.

-- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- $asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators).

```
 ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
   var value = modelValue || viewValue;

   // Lookup user by username
   return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
      then(function onFulfilled() {
        //username exists, this means validation fails
        //throw to reject promise
        throw 'exists' //
      }, function onRejected() {
        //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
        return true;
      });
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will look into this one of the coming days and I will come back on this thereafter.